# Comparison of String and StringBuilder manipulation in terms of memory usage

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

**According to SCJP Study Guide by KathySierra:**

> The java.lang.StringBuffer and java.lang.StringBuilder classes should
>   be used when you have to make modifications to strings of characters.
>   As we discussed, String objects are immutable, so if you choose to do
>   a lot of manipulations with String objects, you will end up with a lot
>   of abandoned String objects in the String pool

To clear out this, I have gone through the code of String class and StringBuilder [source here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/String.java#String).

The simplfied code of String looks like this:

```
public final class String(){
     private final char [] value; //Final helps in immutability, I guess.
     public String (String original){
         value = original.value;
      }
}
```

And `StringBuilder`'s simplified version look like this:

```
public final class StringBuilder{
    char [] value;
    public StringBuilder(String str) {
        value = new Char[(str.length() + 16)]; // 16 here is implementation dependent.
    append(str);
}

public StringBuilder append(String str){

            //Add 'str' characters in value array if its size allows,
        else
            // Create new array of size newCapacity and copy contents of 'value' in that.
            //value = Arrays.copyOf(value, newCapacity);// here old array object is lost.

        return this;
    }
}
```

So let's say we have a case as under:

**Using String class:**

```
String s1 = "abc"; // Creates one object on String pool.
s1 = s1+"def"; // Creates two objects - "def " on String pool
// and "abcdef" on the heap.
```

**If I use StringBuilder, the code becomes:**

```
 StringBuilder s1 = StringBuilder("abc");

 // Creates one String object "abc " on String pool.
 // And one StringBuilder object "abc" on the heap.
 s1.append("def");
 // Creates one string object "def" on String pool.
 // And changes the char [] inside StringBuilder to hold "def" also.
```

In StringBuilder `s2 = s1.append("def");` there are equal chances that the char array holding the string will be replaced by a new char array. The old array is reference less now and will be garbage collected.

**My Query is:**

Using simple String concatenation and `StringBuilder append()` method, the number of `String` objects that go on to the String pool is same.

And according to the code listed above, `StringBuilder` does make use of bigger char arrays in the first place while the `String` object contains a char array of the same length as the string it is holding.

1. How is the usage of `StringBuilder` more efficient than normal
   `String` class for string manipulations?
2. And is the statement given in `SCJP Guide` wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key is the `expandCapacity` function:

```
void expandCapacity(int minimumCapacity) {
    int newCapacity = (value.length + 1) * 2; //important part here
    if (newCapacity < 0) {
        newCapacity = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    } else if (minimumCapacity > newCapacity) {
        newCapacity = minimumCapacity;
    }
    value = Arrays.copyOf(value, newCapacity);
}
```

By resizing the underlying array by a factor of 2 every time a resize is needed, the [amortized time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis) needed to append 1 character is minimized.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array#Geometric_expansion_and_amortized_cost) has a good explanation:

> As n elements are inserted, the capacities form a geometric progression. Expanding the array by any constant proportion ensures that inserting n elements takes O(n) time overall, meaning that each insertion takes amortized constant time. The value of this proportion a leads to a time-space tradeoff: the average time per insertion operation is about a/(a−1), while the number of wasted cells is bounded above by (a−1)n. The choice of a depends on the library or application: some textbooks use a = 2, but Java's ArrayList implementation uses a = 3/2 and the C implementation of Python's list data structure uses a = 9/8.
>
> Many dynamic arrays also deallocate some of the underlying storage if its size drops below a certain threshold, such as 30% of the capacity. This threshold must be strictly smaller than 1/a in order to support mixed sequences of insertions and removals with amortized constant cost.
>
> Dynamic arrays are a common example when teaching amortized analysis.

Now for your particular example it would not make a difference, but you will see the effects when appending lots of characters:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int numAppends = 200000;
    int numRepetitions = 3;
    long[] time1 = new long[numRepetitions];
    long[] time2 = new long[numRepetitions];
    long now;
    for (int k = 0; k < numRepetitions; k++){
        String s = "";
        now = System.nanoTime();
        for(int i = 0; i < numAppends ; i++) {
            s = s + "a";
        }
        time1[k] = (System.nanoTime() - now) / 1000000;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        now = System.nanoTime();
        for(int i = 0; i < numAppends ; i++) {
            sb.append("a");     
        }
        time2[k] = (System.nanoTime() - now) / 1000000;
        System.out.println("Rep "+k+", time1: "+time1[k]+ " ms, time2: " + time2[k] + " ms");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Rep 0, time1: 13509 ms, time2: 7 ms
Rep 1, time1: 13086 ms, time2: 1 ms
Rep 2, time1: 13167 ms, time2: 1 ms
```

Also, I counted the number of times the `Arrays.copyOf()` method is called inside `extendCapacity()` for the benchmark: It's 49 times on the first iteration, but **only 15 times** on the second and third iterations. The output is as follows:

```
newCapacity: 34
newCapacity: 70
newCapacity: 142
newCapacity: 286
newCapacity: 574
newCapacity: 1150
newCapacity: 2302
newCapacity: 4606
newCapacity: 9214
newCapacity: 18430
newCapacity: 36862
newCapacity: 73726
newCapacity: 147454
newCapacity: 294910
newCapacity: 42
Rep 2, time1: 12955 ms, time2: 134 ms
```

Comment: Added microbenchmark and Wikipedia reference for amortized cost.

Comment: My main point was "the string objects created on string pool" will be same in both the case ! So the statement given in `SCJP Guide` is wrong ?

Comment: There will be more String objects created in the first case, namely 200001 String objects. When using StringBuilder, only log2(20000/16) = 10.28, thus 13 arrays will be created, where 16 is the initial array size. Actually, I'll try and count the number of arrays and add it to the answer.

Comment: You are right because the string being appended is `a` everytime. But if we append unique `String` in every iteration . Lets say first "a" then "b" and so on. Then `s.append("a"); s.append("b"); ` will make `a` ,`b` and so on, string objects on String pool. Am i right?

Comment: Only twice, once for "a" and once for "b", but not 20000 times as with the first version.

Comment: Also, I counted the number of times the `Arrays.copyOf` is called inside `extendCapacity` function is called for the 20000 `append`s: It's 49 times for the first repetition, but only 15 times for the other two repetitions. That's pretty close to the value of 13 that I calculated.

Comment: But if we append unique strings in each of the 200000 iterations, the number of objects on String pool created will be same ,no matter we use normal `String` concatenation or `StringBuilder.append();`. Am i correct? Regarding performance i totally agree with you.

Comment: The number will be 20000+15 in the case of StringBuilder, and 20000+20000 in the case of String concatenation. So it's still less. But I agree that if you have 20000 different String literals in your source code then you will have 20000 String objects in the pool. And also if you create 20000 String objects somewhere else in your program.

Comment: Appending does not create objects in the String pool. The number of objects in the String pool is generally about equal to the number of pairs of double quote characters in the source code.

Comment: Those 15 are also not objects i guess.Object is the same always. There are 15 reinitializations of the `Char array`inside the object holding our string.So 15 new `char arrays` will be created.  Right? And `2000` objects will be there on `String Pool` in both the cases.While in case of normal String, `2000` extra objects will be there on heap as compared to only 1 object of StringBuilder.

Comment: @Boann Oh yes of course you are right! So it would be 20000+0 in the case of StringBuilder (assuming you are appending 20000 different String literals)

Comment: It would be 20000(on pool due to literals)+1(on heap due to StringBuilder object). True?

Comment: Only if you call `toString()` on the StringBuilder or an implicit cast to String (and thus a call to `toString()`) takes place. Otherwise it would just be 20000.

Answer (score 3):

It is only more efficient if you are looping to create your strings. If you have a loop that does:

```
String[] strings = { "a", "b", "c", "d" };
String result = "";
for( String s : strings) {
    result += s;
}
```

The `StringBuilder` version will generate less objects and cause less GC:

```
String[] strings = { "a", "b", "c", "d" };
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for( String s : strings) {
    builder.append(s);
}
```

While the first one will cause one object to be sent for GC on every loop run, the second one won't.

Eventually, since the string builder array grows by doubling it's size, you won't have many allocations happening.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you comment on the `SCJP guide` statement about the String pool objects ?

Comment: The statement itself doesn't make much sense, only strings declared as literals go to the pool. The result of concatenating two strings is not included in the string pool.

Comment: the statement is made in this context i guess `String s1="abc";s1=s1+"def";` Now `abc` is lost and sits in `Storage Pool'.But the statement doesn't count `abc` object created on String Pool  when we run `new StringBuilder("").append("abc");`.

Answer (score 2):

Manipulation is more than just concatenating. Imagine you want to insert a character in the middle of a String. How would you do that, since Strings are immutable? You would have to create a new String. With StringBuilder you can `insert(int offset, c)`

See [StringBuilder javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)

You have method like

```
delete(int start, int end)
// Removes the characters in a substring of this sequence.

replace(int start, int end, String str)
// Replaces the characters in a substring of this sequence with characters in the specified String.

reverse()
// Causes this character sequence to be replaced by the reverse of the sequence.

insert(int dstOffset, CharSequence s)
// Inserts the specified CharSequence into this sequence.
```

Answer (score 1):

> How is the usage of StringBuilder more efficient than normal String class for string manipulations?

It's ***vastly*** more efficient when you're performing many manipulations in a loop. Consider any string conversion or replacement function that needs to iterate over individual characters, such as this one to escape `<, >, &, ", '` characters for XML or HTML:

```
public static String xmlEscape(String s) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(
        (int)Math.min(Integer.MAX_VALUE, s.length() * 5L / 4));
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        if (c == '<') sb.append("&lt;");
        else if (c == '>') sb.append("&gt;");
        else if (c == '&') sb.append("&amp;");
        else if (c == '"') sb.append("&quot;");
        else if (c == '\'') sb.append("&#039;");
        else sb.append(c);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

The StringBuilder array is initially sized with a capacity a bit bigger than the input string in order to accommodate the original text plus likely replacements. The output text accumulates in that pre-allocated buffer and it most likely won't need any additional memory allocation during the loop.

If the above function accumulated the output in a String instead of a StringBuilder, it would duplicate the *entire* output again every single time a single character was processed, degrading it to quadratic (i.e., awful!) performance.

To the second question:

> Is the statement given in SCJP Guide is wrong?

To be blunt, yes. It's extremely misleading to say that there will be "abandoned String objects in the String pool". As far as I know, the terminology "String pool" refers only to the *intern pool* such as used by the [`String.intern()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29) method. The only time Strings are automatically put in the intern pool is when the ClassLoader loads a class and loads String literal constants from the source code into memory.

Manipulating String objects at run time certainly *does not* put extra objects in the intern pool (unless you call `.intern()` on purpose).

What the SCJP Guide should say is:

> String objects are immutable, so if you choose to do a lot of manipulations with String objects, you will end up with a lot of abandoned String objects in the **heap**.

Abandoned objects on the heap aren't the biggest problem though, because the garbage collector will swiftly eat them. The real reason to use StringBuilders when doing multiple manipulations is to avoid unnecessary copying of the characters in the first place. That makes a massive difference to the performance as shown in @jmiserez' benchmark.

Comment: Won't every `append("&lt;")` will create one `&lt;` object on String pool ? My question was more towards the `String` pool objects being created? Thanks

Comment: @AmanArora No, absolutely not, and this is true whether you append to a String or a StringBuilder. String literals are loaded into memory **once** when the class is loaded. Because they are constant, there is no need to create new ones per use or per call.